# How do I convert the weekday command so that I can manually pick the day for each task rather than it detecting it automatically?

Tags: vbscript

When I started on this I wasn't aware that I had to be able to select each daily task manually and pick each task whenever I want, I'm trying to figure out how to convert it into a manual entry so I don't have to rework the whole thing, bear in mind I'm very new to vbscript so if there's an obvious solution I apologize. I'm still working on the later days of the week to finish this.

```
dtmToday = Date()

dtmDayOfWeek = DatePart("w", dtmToday)

'Select case to pickup the value of day of the week and call procedure
Select Case dtmDayOfWeek
    Case 1 
    Call Sunday()
    Case 2 
    Call Monday()
    Case 3 
    Call Tuesday()
    Case 4 
    Call Wednesday()
    Case 5 
    Call Thursday()
    Case 6 
    Call Friday()
    Case 7 
    Call Saturday()
End Select


'Sunday procedure will execute from select case
sub Sunday()
'defining variables
dim wshShell
dim path
dim fso
'setting up the environment to run vbscript
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
' Execute the command and append to the text file
WShShell.run "cmd /c ping -n 10 youtube.com >> ping.txt", hidden
wscript.quit
End sub

'Monday procedure will execute from select case
sub Monday()
'defining variables
dim wshShell
dim path
dim fso
'setting up the environment to run vbscript
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
' to execute the command and append to the text file using >> if you want to text to be overriden use >
WShShell.run "cmd /c netstat >> netstat.txt", hidden
wscript.quit
End sub

'Tuesday procedure will execute from select case
sub Tuesday()
'defining variables
dim wshShell
dim path
dim fso
'setting up the environment to run vbscript
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
' to execute the command and append to the text file using >> if you want to text to be overriden use >
WShShell.run "cmd /c arp -a >> arp.txt", hidden
wscript.quit
End sub

sub Wednesday()
'defining variables
dim wshShell
dim path
dim fso
'setting up the environment to run vbscript
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WShShell.run "cmd /c nbstat -n >> nbstat.txt", hidden
wscript.quit
End Sub

sub Thursday()
'defining variables
dim wshShell
dim path
dim fso
'setting up the environment to run vbscript
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WShShell.run "cmd /c tracert -n 10 youtube.com >> nbstat.txt", hidden
wscript.quit
End Sub
```

Comment: That is some heavy duplication of code.

Comment: The `dtmDayOfWeek` is just a number so you could use [`InputBox()` Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/3yfdhzk5(v=vs.84)) to ask for the number of the day of the week 1 - 7.

Answer (score 2):

You need first optimize your code to avoid heavy duplication as @Lankymart was mentioned it in his comment, by writing one function and call it when you need it, and to store all your commands into an array for easy access by their index.

So your code can be written like that :

```
Option Explicit
' We define our Global variables 
Dim Title,ArrCommands,strcmd,dtmDayOfWeek,IndexCommand,UserInput
Title = "Run command line based on the Day Of Week"
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' We define and store our commands lines into an array
ArrCommands = Array(_
"ping -n 10 youtube.com >> ping.txt",_
"netstat >> netstat.txt",_
"arp -a >> arp.txt",_
"Color 0A & Title Running nbtstat command & nbtstat -n",_
"Color 0A & Title Running Tracert command & tracert youtube.com",_
"Color 0A & Title Running Ipconfig command & Ipconfig /all",_
"Color 0A & Title Running netstat command & netstat -ano"_
)
'-------------------------------Main Program---------------------------------------
Do While Not IsDate(UserInput)
    UserInput = InputBox("Type a date here example 24/06/2020",Title,"24/06/2020")
    dtmDayOfWeek = MyWeekday(UserInput)
    IndexCommand = dtmDayOfWeek - 1
Loop

MsgBox "Day of the Week = "& dtmDayOfWeek & vbCrlf &_
"The command will be executed is : "& ArrCommands(IndexCommand),vbInformation,Title

'Select case to pickup the value of day of the week 
Select Case dtmDayOfWeek
Case 1 
    Call Execute(ArrCommands(IndexCommand),0)
Case 2 
    Call Execute(ArrCommands(IndexCommand),0)
Case 3 
    Call Execute(ArrCommands(IndexCommand),0)
Case 4 
    Call Execute(ArrCommands(IndexCommand),1)
Case 5 
    Call Execute(ArrCommands(IndexCommand),1)
Case 6 
    Call Execute(ArrCommands(IndexCommand),1)
Case 7 
    Call Execute(ArrCommands(IndexCommand),1)
End Select

'MsgBox "Command line is done",vbInformation,Title
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function MyWeekday(MyDate)
    If MyDate = "" Then MyDate = Date()
    If IsDate(MyDate) Then
        MyWeekDay = Weekday(MyDate)
        Exit Function
    End If
End Function
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub Execute(StrCmd,Console)
    Dim ws,MyCmd
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
    'The console = 0 means will be running in hidden mode
    If Console = 0 Then
        MyCmd = "CMD /C " & StrCmd & " "
        ws.run MyCmd,Console,True 
    End If
    'The console = 1 means will be running in not hidden mode
    If Console = 1 Then
        MyCmd = "CMD /K " & StrCmd & " "
        ws.run MyCmd,Console,True
    End If
End Sub
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Good effort, wasn’t going to rewrite it for them. Only concern it might be too much of a refactor if they are new to VBScript or programming in general.

Comment: Thank you @Hackoo you're a lifesaver, would it be possible to have just a little more help with this assignment in particular? It's actually almost done, it's just the commands for Friday and Saturday are a bit different, for Friday I need to run ipconfig and display the output on the screen, and for Saturday I need to run hostname and display the output on the screen. After that I'm finished, I just don't know how to add that into the array you made. Also apparently for the Tracert it's saying -n is not a recognized command? Not really sure what that means either

Comment: @SirRevenant On Firday you want to run this command `Ipconfig /all` ? and on Saturday what command ?

Comment: Sorry I should've clarified @Hackoo, for Saturday I need the hostname and then have the results displayed on screen, my teacher was a little vague on what that is. But I think it's the computer's name, something along the lines of           
```WScript.Echo CreateObject("WScript.Network").ComputerName``` Is there some kind of hostname command that I don't know about?

Comment: @Hackoo Hey, I'm about to head to work so I apologize if I'm AFK for awhile, thank you again for how much you've already helped me.

Comment: @SirRevenant Check my last edit answer and if it is OK for you don't forget to accept it as answer !

Comment: @Hackoo It's not quite what I needed unfortunately, for the ```Ipconfig / all``` I need the results to just display in a ```Msgbox``` rather than a text file like all the other ones in the array. I need to do the same thing with the `hostname` but I'm still not sure what that actually means

Comment: @SirRevenant This is sounding more and more like a homework assignment.